# Add values from JSP to another table in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to add a few details to a table named `questionpaper` from my front end JSP and from another table named `questions`.

In table `questionpaper` I have a column named `ExamID` to which I have to add a value of `ExamId column` from another table named `question`. This `ExamId value` has to be added simultaneously with the data added from the JSP page. The data from the JSP page is getting added without any error but the `ExamId` cannot be added simultaneously.

```
public int QuestionPaper(Questions paramQues) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String query ="insert into questionpaper(Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,Answer,Marks,NegMarks,ExamId)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    int status=0;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlineexam", "root", "admin");
        PreparedStatement stat1 = con.prepareStatement(query);
        if((paramQues.getAns1()!=null)&&(paramQues.getAns2()!=null)&&(paramQues.getAns3()!=null)&&(paramQues.getAns4()!=null)&&(paramQues.getMarks()!=null)&&(paramQues.getNegM()!=null)&&(paramQues.getQues()!=null))
        {
            System.out.println("implementation  "+paramQues.getOption());
            System.out.println("Marks-->"+paramQues.getMarks());
            System.out.println("Ans->>"+paramQues.getAns1());
            stat1.setString(1,paramQues.getQues());
            stat1.setString(2,paramQues.getAns1());
            stat1.setString(3,paramQues.getAns2());
            stat1.setString(4,paramQues.getAns3());
            stat1.setString(5,paramQues.getAns4());
            stat1.setString(6,paramQues.getOption());
            stat1.setInt(7,paramQues.getMarks());
            stat1.setInt(8,paramQues.getNegM());
            System.out.println("Ans->>"+paramQues.getAns1());
            
            String query2="SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY ExamId DESC LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement stat2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
            
            ResultSet rs1 = stat2.executeQuery(query2);
            Integer Examid= rs1.getInt("ExamId");
            System.out.println("exam id-->"+Examid);
            
            stat1.setInt(9,Examid);
            stat1.executeUpdate();  
            Integer TotalQues=  rs1.getInt("TotalQuestions");
            
            String query3="SELECT * FROM questionpaper ORDER BY PaperId DESC LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement stat3 = con.prepareStatement(query3);
            ResultSet rs2 = stat3.executeQuery(query3);
            Integer PaperId= rs2.getInt("PaperId");
            
            if(PaperId<=TotalQues)
            
                status=1; 
            else
                status=0;
        }
      
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception in FacultyTry->" + e);
    }
    
return status;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Answer:l
j
d
d
options-->o3
Marks-->2
NegMarks-->1
implementation  o3
Marks-->2
Ans->>l
Ans->>l
Exception in FacultyTry->java.sql.SQLException
```

Comment: in your catch statement, print the stack trace using e.printStackTrace(System.out) and correctly identify which line trows the exception, and post the line

Comment: Is your table name `questions` or `question` ? Have you checked your SQL query ? Is that contains proper table name & column names ?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned, your tables contain `ExamID` column & you are using `ExamId` in SQL query. Either of the below query contains wrong column name.

**Your SQL query :**

```
String query ="insert into questionpaper(Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,Answer,Marks,
    NegMarks,ExamId)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

OR 

String query2="SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY ExamId DESC LIMIT 1";
```

**Required SQL Query :**

```
String query ="insert into questionpaper(Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,Answer,Marks,
    NegMarks,ExamID)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

OR 

String query2="SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY ExamID DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't need to prepare a statement that has no parameters denoted by `?`.

Use the statement to execute query

```
ResultSet rs1 = stat1.executeQuery(query2);
```

or

```
Statement stat2 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = stat2.executeQuery(query2);
```